# Sequence slider JS doesn't work with the Foundation framework JS files

Tags: plugins, frameworks, slider, sequence, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Foundation framework on my website and now i'm implementing the Sequence slider it works just fine but only when i outcomment the following Foundation JS files in the head:

```
<script src="/plugins/foundation/modernizr.foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/plugins/foundation/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/plugins/foundation/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, for some other functionalities of foundation i do need these files.
Has anyone else had this problem before and found a solution? 
Could anyone give me some tips about where the problem could be?

i just found out when i look at it with firebug, this is what the console says:

```
$("#sequence").sequence is not a function
var sequence = $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");
```

This is part of the javascript i put in my head to initiate the code on document ready;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(1000);
    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);
    });

    var options = {
        autoPlay: false,
        nextButton: true,
        prevButton: true
    }
    var sequence = $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");

    $('.details, .info-button') .mouseover(function() {
        $('.title').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }) .mouseout (function() {
        $('.title').css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered i figured out a solution on my own.

It appears the problem was the order in which the files were called upon in the head.

The order it didn't work in i had sequence & jquery before foundation.

Once i switched these in order both plugins seem to work just fine..

This is the order it's working in:

```
<script src="/plugins/foundation/modernizr.foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/plugins/foundation/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/plugins/foundation/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/sequence.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have this same issue but this solution doesn't seem to work well. for me it still to occur TypeError: $(...).sequence is not a function